# How to change an <input> field's VALUE attribute in real time with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I want to change the value of an **input** field in real time as the user types in another **input** field, preferably using regular JS and not JQuery.

Example: User types a random value into **#input_1**, and at the SAME TIME, **#input_2** receives whatever the user is typing and sets it at its value.

If the user deletes a number from the **#input_1** value, **#input_2** follows and deletes the same number from its value.

This all in **real time** and preferably **without** a button press to **trigger** the function that does this.

Comment: Did you google this?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Tried, but couldn't find anything that fits what I'm looking for.

Comment: `inp1.oninput=x=>inp2.value=inp1.value;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/dn6h0fre/ This took me less than a minute to do :)

Comment: Without capturing a button press the only way would be to use a timeout/interval.  That would be way less efficient.

Comment: @james that is not true.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I consider any "oninput" "onkeyup" type events to be capturing a button press.

Comment: @James I think (pretty sure) that the OP is referring to a button press as clicking a `button` element.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I respectfully disagree.  I think they mean a keyboard press.

Comment: @PolarDog what say you?

Comment: @James question says "user types into input1"... using what? Not a keyboard?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Maybe you're right!  They don't mention a button in the html but it could mean that too.

Comment: @PolarDog you should show us what you have tried, please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Easy ;)

```html
<input id="input1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('input2').value=this.value" />
<input id="input2" />
```

Comment: This will certainly work, but in general it is recommended to not use inline Javascript attributes. Doing so encourages repetitiveness of code and blurs the separation of concerns.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Depends on the use dude ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to implement this. Here's how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<input id="sourceField" />
<input id="destinationField" />
```

JS:

```
// When the page is done loading and rendering...
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    // Get the appropriate elements
    const sourceField = document.getElementById('sourceField')
    const destinationField = document.getElementById('destinationField')

    // When the user types some input into the first text field...
    sourceField.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
        // Set the value of the destination field to the value of the source field.
        destinationField.value = sourceField.value
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you _need_ the `DOMContentLoaded`? As long as it's below the element it should be fine

Comment: @YaakovAinspan You're correct, but we don't know where OP will be putting this JS, so I prefer to include it.

Comment: I'd be adding it to the page itself, if that's what you mean. Not in a separate .js file.

Comment: @PolarDog Regardless of whether your JS is in a separate file or inline in your HTML, if the `<script>` element that loads it comes after the `<input>` elements in your HTML, you don't need the `DOMContentLoaded`. But I like putting my `<script>` elements in the `<head>` of my HTML.

Comment: I keep it just under my `<head>` but above my `<body>`.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat, just be consistent. Also, if you put it in your `<head>` and load from an external file, you can use the new-ish `defer` attribute to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it like this**

You need to select the first input (on an event) and take value from that input and update in the second one.

```js
function handle(e){
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  console.log(input1)
  document.getElementById('input2').value = input1;
}
```

```html
<input id='input1' onkeyup="handle()" value=""/>
<input id='input2'  value="" />
```